# ftp_get memory leak

Tags: php, ftp

Currently I have a script which does something of this sort:

```
//Connect to the FTP server    
$conn_id = connect_to_server($server, $user, $password);

//Switch to the directory with the files
ftp_chdir($conn_id, $directory);

//Get the contents of the current directory then iterate over them
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");


//loop through files and download them
foreach($contents as $file) {
  ftp_get($conn_id, $local_filename, $file, FTP_BINARY);
}
```

The problem is `ftp_get` balloons out of control, and runs out memory. The only solution I've found is closing the connection before every `ftp_get` connection.

Is there a way to free up the `ftp_get` memory without closing the connection?

Comment: Update to the latest version, if the problem persists [file a bug report](http://bugs.php.net) I guess. Meanwhile you could check whether `ftp_fget` shows similar behavior or solves your problem for now.